# Selenium IDE Failed: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I'm very new to automated testing and i've done automated testing recording my test case using Selenium IDE but  then i get the following error while testing out my recording in selenium IDE.
[image]

the element is a form that has autofilled input like this
[image]
How do I resolve the error?